# I want to show related data together from different APIs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I have two APIs:

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getQueryCountriesList().subscribe(arg => {
         this.countryDatas = arg;
       });
       this.getQueryNights().subscribe(obj => {
        this.nightDatas = obj;
      });
........
......
  getQueryCountriesList(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/Visitor?tourType="+ this.tourType +"&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge);
  }
  getQueryNights(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + "/Nights?tourType="+ this.tourType +"&year=" + this.selectedYear + "&month=" + this.selectedMonth +"&gender=" + this.selectedGender + "&age="+this.selectedAge);
  }
```

each data have same id, I want to show visits(from first API) and nights(second API) next to each other in table:
component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let country of countryDatas; let nights; of: nightDatas">
    <th [id]="country.countryId + '1'">{{ country.countryNameGe }}</th>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '2'">{{ country.value }}</td>
    <td [id]="country.countryId + '3'">{{ nights.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

with the following code I get only nights or only visits in every column randomly

Comment: You should pre-process both responses and join them to single array with relevant relation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Promise.all()** to wait for the two api to return response, it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rxJS's power. In this case, you can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';


ngOnInit(): void {
  forkJoin({
    countries: this.getQueryCountriesList(),
    nights: this.getQueryNights()
  }).subscribe(({countries, nights}) => {
      this.countryDatas = countries;
      this.nightDatas = nights;
  });
```

So, what is happing here? With `forkJoin` you are waiting that both observables from your API to be emitted, then emit an object that contains your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rxjs [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) operator that will wait for both observables to emit at least one value. And from there, build your array that contains both values:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
 
ngOnInit(): void {
    queryCountriesList$ = this.getQueryCountriesList();
    queryNights$ = this.getQueryNights();
     combineLatest([queryCountriesList$,queryNights$])
    .subscribe(([queryCountriesList, queryNights]) => 
    {
        // create your object here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combineLatest from RxJS operators. Visit https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const weight = of(70, 72, 76, 79, 75);
const height = of(1.76, 1.77, 1.78);
const bmi = combineLatest([weight, height]).pipe(
  map(([w, h]) => w / (h * h)),
);
bmi.subscribe(x => console.log('BMI is ' + x));

// With output to console:
// BMI is 24.212293388429753
// BMI is 23.93948099205209
// BMI is 23.671253629592222
```

In your case:

```
const combined = combineLatest([
  getQueryCountriesList(),
  getQueryNights(),
]).pipe(
  map(([countries, nights]) => {
    // your logic to combine object, make sure to return the final value
  })
);
combined.subscribe((x) => console.log("Final result is " + x));
```